# NgbPopover closes as soon as I try to change a value on the ng-template (Angular)

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, popover, ng-bootstrap, timepicker

I am using `ngbPopover` with `ngb-datepicker` and `ngb-timepicker`

```
<div class="input-group">              
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="createdStartDate" disabled="true"
      [value]="createdStartDateValue?(createdStartDateValue|date:'dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm'):createdStartDateLabel">               
    
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" type="button" placement="bottom" popoverTitle="Select Date Time"  [ngbPopover]="dateTimePicker"  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></button>
          <ng-template #dateTimePicker>
            <ngb-datepicker [ngModel]="createdStartDate" (ngModelChange)="getCreatedStartDatetime()" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
            </ngb-datepicker>
            
            <ngb-timepicker [ngModel]="createdStartTime" (ngModelChange)="createdStartTime=$event;getCreatedStartDatetime()" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
            </ngb-timepicker>              
          </ng-template>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: closing]

It is closing as soon as I try to add some input in the Timepicker.
How to stop this from happening?

Comment: why not use a ngbDropDown?, BTW In this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655320/are-there-no-datetime-picker-for-angular-7/63656402#63656402 are some very closed your'e trying

Comment: ngbDropdown does not disable the input box. The user should not be allowed to enter the date manually. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I want a disabled input box and a button with calender icon. @Eliseo

Comment: you need use `<input ... [attr.disabled]="true">`. this disable the input. If you're using bootstrap, you can also use `<input ... readonly>` if use bootstrap 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css

```
.dropdown-toggle.calendar::after
{
  border:0
}
button.calendar, button.calendar:active {
  width: 2.75rem;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACIAAAAcCAYAAAAEN20fAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAAEUSURBVEiJ7ZQxToVAEIY/YCHGxN6XGOIpnpaEsBSeQC9ArZbm9TZ6ADyBNzAhQGGl8Riv4BLAWAgmkpBYkH1b8FWT2WK/zJ8ZJ4qiI6XUI3ANnGKWBnht2/ZBDRK3hgVGNsCd7/ui+JkEIrKtqurLpEWaphd933+IyI3LEIdpCYCiKD6HcuOa/nwOa0ScJEnk0BJg0UTUWJRl6RxCYEzEmomsIlPU3IPW+grIAbquy+q6fluy/28RIBeRMwDXdXMgXLj/B2uimRXpui4D9sBeRLKl+1N+L+t6RwbWrZliTTTr1oxYtzVWiTQAcRxvTX+eJMnlUDaO1vpZRO5NS0x48sIwfPc87xg4B04MCzQi8hIEwe4bl1DnFMCN2zsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 23px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

The html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" [attr.disabled]="true"
         name="dp" >
        <div ngbDropdown class="input-group-append d-inline-block" placement="bottom-right">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                Your calendar and your timer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also use a svg, e.g.

```
.dropdown-toggle.calendar2::after
{
  border:0
}

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" [attr.disabled]="true"
             name="dp" >
            <div ngbDropdown class="input-group-append d-inline-block" placement="bottom-right">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar2" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                    Your calendar and your timer
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```